# How to write a rolling window that is endless/circular?

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to create a rolling window that wraps back to the start of the vector as the tail of the window passes the end of the vector (assume vector length is always at least as great as window size). I could effectively achieve this by repeating my vector an infinite number of times, then applying a standard rolling window.

There might be a better name for what I'm trying to do, I'm not sure.

I'm working in R, and one weird/ hacked way is to make sure of the way R fills matrices:

```
# Number of windows
n.reps <- 10

# Window Size
time <- 12

# Vector I want to applying the window to
# Assume that the length of this vector is always >= window size
t.lvls <- c(0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1)

# If I know n.reps ahead of time, I can simply create n.reps
# vectors with the appropriate frameshift by using 
# matrix() and how it repeats values.
# This is effective but inelegant.
ref <- matrix(t.lvls, byrow=TRUE, nrow=n.reps, ncol=time+1)

use.lvls <- list() # holds the values in each window
for(i in 1:n.reps){
    use.lvls[[i]] <- ref[i,-(time+1)]
}
```

I used the `matrix()` so that I didn't have to actually program the rolling window part, but I suppose I could always just do something like `rep(t.lvls, ceiling(n.reps/time))` and loop through that ... but for large n.reps I might not want to go this route (same for matrix approach).

1) Is there a name for what I'm trying to do?

2) Is there a more elegant way to program this?

Edit: expected output (which is achieved through the above code)

```
list(c(0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1), 
c(0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 0), 
c(0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
c(0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.25), 
c(0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25), 
c(0.75, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25), 
c(0.75, 0.75, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75), 
c(0.75, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75), 
c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.75))
```

Comment: What's the use case? R implicitly performs vector recycling in many instances. Also, some special applications are handled in different functions/packages like `filter` and `zoo::rollapply`.

Comment: @A.Webb These are parameter values that I'm supplying to a simulation model. I want a parameter value in each spot. But in general, endless rolling window sounds like something that could be used for multiple purposes.

Comment: @nongkrong I'm not sure what you have in mind ... elaborate?

Comment: @nongkrong oops ... corrected code and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of the `%%` suggestion by @nongkrong I wrote the following function:

```
f5 <- function(){
    len.tlvl <- length(t.lvls)
    vals <- (1:time + rep(0:(n.reps-1), each=time))%%len.tlvl
    use.inds <- matrix(vals, nrow=time)
    use.inds[use.inds==0] <- len.tlvl
    matrix(t.lvls[use.inds], nrow=time)
}
```

As a bonus, it works even when `t.lvls` (the vector) has length that is less then `time` (the window size).

While I was polishing this function, I saw the answer by @A. Webb

```
rolliter<-function(values,window){
    i<-0;
    values<-c(values,values);
    function() {i<<-i%%window+1;values[i:(i+window-1)]}
}
f6 <- function(){
    nxt<-rolliter(t.lvls,12)
    replicate(10,nxt(),simplify=T)
}
```

I modified it so that output is a `matrix` (I know that's not the format of my original 'intended output', but I'm seeing that it shouldn't matter). Note that the `f6` function doesn't work when the length of `t.lvls` is shorter than `time` (again, not a requirement in my original question).

Comparing computation times for these two approaches:

```
> microbenchmark(f5(), f6())
Unit: microseconds
 expr    min     lq      mean  median      uq      max neval
 f5() 33.789 36.436  39.28334 37.8530 40.3800    62.77   100
 f6() 61.890 66.283 359.21862 69.9395 77.9295 28811.27   100
```

Both are fast and produce similar results, but the `f5()` approach is a bit quicker.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an endless supply, consider an iterator

```
rolliter<-function(values,window) {
  i<-0;
  values<-c(values,values);
  function() {i<<-i%%window+1;values[i:(i+window-1)]}}
```

To match your output

```
nxt<-rolliter(t.lvls,12)
replicate(10,nxt(),simplify=FALSE)
```

But then you can keep calling `nxt()` for more.

Comment: thx; see my answer/ approach for time comparison. Looks like we were both inspired by @nongkrong mentioning `%%`